# Function defined without recursion theorem

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I want to show the existence of a function $f$ with domain $n+1\in\omega$ and such that $f(0)=\emptyset$ and $\forall m\in n(f(m+1)=\{f(m)\})$ without to use recursion theorem.

I think in replacement axiom to do my task.

I define $\phi(n,x)\equiv(x\ \text{is a function})\wedge dom(x)=n+1\wedge\forall y\in n((y+1,\{x(y)\})\in x)$.

Is it my formula well defined and is sufficent to get my aim?

Answer (score 0):

Let k be the precessor of n.
k in n and f(n) = f(k + 1) = {f(n)}.
Consequently the big no, no:  f(n) in f(n).

Comment: There was a wrong in the definition of the function. It was fixed.